# Using Nearest on a 2D List (seeing extra parentheses)

Tags: syntax

I am working a problem involving colliding particles.  I define a list of particle diameters (effectively a bin distribution).  I need to know if two particles collide, in what bin diameter should I place the resulting combination?

To do this, I define the bin diameters, and derive the associated volume (a 1D list).  The permutations of the combination are then defined as a 2D list, (where the ij element is the combined volume of the ith and jth element of the reference list).  I'd thought to then use `Nearest` to determine the correct volume bin, and then backtrack to the diameter bin.  I think I'm close to the right syntax, but I'm getting extra () in the output.  How can I get rid of those?  I tried `Flatten`, but I didn't see a change (which tells me I'm probably using it incorrectly).

```
Bins = {0.523, 0.542, 0.583, 0.626, 0.673, 0.723, 0.777, 0.835, 0.898,
 0.965, 1.037, 1.114, 1.197, 1.286, 1.382, 1.486, 1.596, 1.715, 
1.843, 1.981, 2.129, 2.288, 2.458, 2.642, 2.839, 3.051, 3.278, 
3.523, 3.786, 4.068, 4.371, 4.698, 5.048, 5.425, 5.829, 6.264, 
6.732, 7.234, 7.774, 8.354, 8.977, 9.647, 10.37, 11.14, 11.97, 
12.86, 13.82, 14.86, 15.96, 17.15, 18.43, 19.81}*10^-6;
BinVolume = (4/3)*Pi*Bins^3; 
CombinedVolume = Table[BinVolume[[i]] + BinVolume[[j]], {i, 52}, {j, 52}]; 
TestOutput=MatrixForm[Table[Nearest[BinVolume, CombinedVolume[[i, j]]], {i, 52}, {j, 52}]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `MatrixForm[
 Flatten /@ 
  Table[Nearest[BinVolume, CombinedVolume[[i, j]]], {i, 52}, {j, 52}]]` or `Table[First@Nearest[BinVolume, CombinedVolume[[i, j]]], {i, 52}, {j, 
  52}]`

Comment: Thanks!  So if I'm interpreting the code correctly /@ is shorthand for the Map function, which means I'm telling Mm to Flatten each individual entry in the table; thus removing the braces.

I think the second variation (First@Nearest) does the same sort of thing, but instead of removing the braces, it's using the table-of-tables thing I was creating.  First would pull the first entry of each subtable, so instead of having a table-of-tables, I wind up with a table-of-first-entries-of-a-table?

Comment: Exactly. You've got it.